# Meaning of Off In the following sentence

Tags: meaning

[The England captain scored 148 **off** 71 balls against Afghanistan at Old Trafford](https://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/2019-world-cup-eoin-morgan-smashes-17-sixes-breaks-odi-record/article28065607.ece)

What is the meaning of **off**. Does it mean **to get out off**?

I looked up its meaning in dictionary but didn't find anything.

Comment: You might have better luck with this one in the [sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com) exchange

Answer (score 1):

In cricket, this is just the usual way of describing how many runs were scored from a certain number of balls.  The batsman received 71 balls from the bowlers, and scored 148 runs, which is a very high score.

The [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket/48679823) wrote a very similar sentence: "The captain hammered 17 sixes in making 148 from 71 balls, ..."

Answer (score 0):

In cricket lingo, it simply means "in", so the phrase means **148 runs in 71 balls.**

Comment: That answer has already been given.